Print return & policy on every alternate page(2nd,4th,6th...) in crystal report
I have to print a receipt in which every odd page has billing info in detail section. after that payment detail in group footer section. How to print return policy on every even number page?

One option is to split your PH section to PHa and PHb. PHb should provide the content of the Return Policy. Suppress PHa on even pages, and suppress PHb on odd pages. Tweak the size PHb so it allows nothing else on that page. You may need to add the Return Policy also to RF section if you need it on the last page.
Another option is to use a 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tool that can export the report to pdf, and inject another 1-page pdf (the Return Policy in your case) as back pages in the exported pdf. At least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools listed here provides that functionality (including the ability to print or email the merged pdf).
